# Protractor code failing due to module exports

Tags: javascript, angular, protractor, e2e-testing

In my Protractor framework, I am using a POM model, so a lot of code resides in different `.js` files, which are then called into , at necessary junctions, to have the e2e tests.

I have a `CompleteProfile.js` file (dummy name), where I have a condition,

```
if profile_flag ===100,
   then do nothing
else
   complete profile (includes a lot of forms)
```

For the `else` portion, I have the code in a different`fillCustomerForms.js` file, whose code is something like this

```
var completeprofile = function(){
    this.locator = element(by.css('some_css_locator'));
    this.locator.click();
    browser.sleep(2000);
}

module.exports={
    profileComplete1 = completeprofile
}
```

I'm using this from `fillCustomerForms.js` in my `CompleteProfile.js` as

```
 var Profile = require('./fillCustomerForms.js');
 var c_profile = new Profile.profileComplete1();

 var compl_profile = function(){

   this.someFunction= function(){
       profile_flag = "90"
       if profile_flag ==="100"{
           then do nothing;
       }else{
           c_profile.completeprofile();
      }
      }
      }

 module.exports={
      finalExp = compl_profile
     }
```

Inside my `spec.js`, I am calling the `CompleteProfile.js` as

```
 var Profile = require('./CompleteProfile.js');
 var co_profile = new Profile.finalExp();

  describe("Modules",()=>{
    it('Modules that load other things',()=>{
         //do other things neccessary
      });
  });

  describe("Module",()=>{
        it("should do something,"()=>{
        co_profile.someFunction();    
  });
 });
```

The first `describe` block is the one that loads the browser and checks for the URL and other test cases. My issue is when if I add the second `describe` block, then the URL that is sent in first `describe` block is rendered empty i.e. Chrome loads without any URL, and errors out due to timeout error. I have checked the code and it seems fine. What did I do wrong here.

I'm guessing this might have to do with some basics of JS, that I might have overlooked, but right now I'm not able to figure this one out.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in your second testcase (the `it` function). Every callback of each testcase in Mocha requires to be resolved or rejected. e.g:

```
it('should ...', done => { 
   /* assertion */ 
   done(/* passing a new instance of Error will reject the testcase*/); 
});`.
```

The called function doesn't not return anything in the provided code snippet, I don't really see what you're trying to test for.

Comment: The tests use `Jasmine 2.0` framework, not Mocha, so the syntax is not a problem here.